# how can i remove an item from this listview builder after being draged to the darg target

Tags: flutter, listview, drag-and-drop, dragtarget

i am new with dart, i tryed to build a verbes game with drag and drop i created a model then the draggable widget and the drag target then i build a list view with the data that i pushed from the main but the problem is that i didn't find how to remove the widget from the listview after it is draged to the right place i am sooo stack so please if any body can help me i will be grateful

this is the class

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:templates/Model/equation.model.dart';
import 'package:confetti/confetti.dart';

class Equations extends StatefulWidget {

  final Equation equation;
  Equations(this.equation);
  @override
  _EquationsState createState() => _EquationsState();
}

ConfettiController confettiController =
    ConfettiController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2));


class _EquationsState extends State<Equations> {

  bool showIcons = false;

List<String> responses = [];

bool checkResults() {
  bool result = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    if (widget.equation.props[i].result.toString() != responses[i]) {
      result = false;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    responses = List.filled(widget.equation.props.length, "");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
            body: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: ConfettiWidget(
                      confettiController: confettiController,
                      colors: [
                        Colors.red,
                        Colors.blue,
                        Colors.green,
                        Colors.yellow,
                        Colors.purple,
                        Colors.pink,
                        Colors.brown
                      ],
                      shouldLoop: true,
                      numberOfParticles: 28,
                      emissionFrequency: 0.07,
                      blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality.explosive,
                      gravity: 0.1,
                      minBlastForce: 12,
                      maxBlastForce: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      FittedBox(
                        child: Text(
                          widget.equation.question,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: widget.equation.props.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 4),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      FittedBox(
                                        child: Text(
                                          widget.equation.props[index].fields,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                        ),
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      ),
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Container(
                                        width: 50,
                                        child: TextField(
                                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                          onChanged: (value) {
                                            String removeSpace =
                                                value.replaceAll(" ", "");
                                            String replaceVirgule = removeSpace
                                                .replaceAll(",", ".");
                                            responses[index] = replaceVirgule;
                                            print("before :" + value);
                                            print("after :" + replaceVirgule);
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Icon(
                                        showIcons
                                            ? widget.equation.props[index].result.toString() ==
                                                    responses[index]
                                                ? Icons.verified
                                                : Icons.error
                                            : null,
                                        color: widget.equation.props[index].result.toString() ==
                                                responses[index]
                                            ? Colors.green
                                            : Colors.red,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (checkResults()) {
                                confettiController.play();
                                Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
                                  confettiController.stop();
                                });
                              }
                              setState(() {
                                showIcons = true;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'الإجابة',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            )));
  }
}
```

this is the widgets of drag target and draggable

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:templates/Model/verbe.model.dart';

class DragWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title_data;
//dragoble
  final String title_drag;
  final Color colors_d;
  //feedback
  final String title_fb;
  final Color colors_fb;
//childwhen it is darged
  final String title_child;
  final Color colors_child;

  DragWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title_data,
      required this.title_child,
      required this.title_drag,
      required this.title_fb,
      required this.colors_child,
      required this.colors_d,
      required this.colors_fb})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable<String>(
      // Data is the value this Draggable stores.
      data: title_data,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // radius of 10
          color: colors_d, // green as background color
        ),
        height: 100,
        width: 100.0,
        // color: colors_d,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            title_drag,
            textScaleFactor: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      feedback: Material(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 100.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // radius of 10
            color: colors_fb,
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
           title_fb,
              textScaleFactor: 2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      childWhenDragging: Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), // radius of 10
          color: colors_child, // green as background color
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            title_child,
            textScaleFactor: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DargTarget1 extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isDroped;
  String title_data;
  String part1;
  String part2;
  String prop;
  DargTarget1({
    Key? key,
    required this.title_data,
    required this.prop,
    required this.part1,
    required this.part2,
    required this.isDroped,
  });

  @override
  State<DargTarget1> createState() => _DargTarget1State();
}

class _DargTarget1State extends State<DargTarget1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          DragTarget<String>(
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              List<dynamic> accepted,
              List<dynamic> rejected,
            ) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    widget.part1,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  DottedBorder(
                    borderType: BorderType.RRect,
                    radius: Radius.circular(12),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    dashPattern: [6],
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 60,
                        color: widget.isDroped ? Colors.green : null,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                !widget.isDroped ? '......' : widget.prop,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25))),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.part2,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
            onAccept: (data) {
              setState(() {
                showSnackBarGlobal(context, 'أحسنت');
                widget.isDroped = true;
              });
            },
            onWillAccept: (data) {
              return data == widget.title_data;
            },
            onLeave: (data) {
              showSnackBarGlobal(context, 'خطأ');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void showSnackBarGlobal(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(
      message,
      textScaleFactor: 2,
    )));
  }
}
//this function remove data from the list
```

this is the modle i am working with

```
  List<Verbe> verbe;
  Verbes(this.verbe);
}

class Verbe {
  String part1;
  String part2;

  bool isDropped;
  String data_test0;
  String prop;
  Verbe(this.isDropped, this.data_test0, this.prop, this.part1, this.part2);
}
```

and this is the data i am sending from the main

```
 List<Verbe> itemsVerbess = [
    Verbe(false, 'a', 'ferai', "je", ""),
    Verbe(false, 'b', 'feras', "tu", ""),
    Verbe(false, 'c', 'fera', "il", ""),
    Verbe(false, 'd', 'ferons', "nous", ""),
    Verbe(false, 'e', 'ferez', "vous", ""),
    Verbe(false, 'f', 'feront', "ils", "")
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, I see the solution like this:

1. Create a flag **isDraggedToTarget** = false;
2. When it is dragged, call setState and set flag to true
3. Under widget at ListView write condition like that:

   if(isDraggedToTarget!=true)

   Container(),

So when the flag is false you will see Widget, and it will dissappear if flag is true

Comment: no need to add a new flag becase i have widget.verbess.verbe[index].isDropped change the state evry time iu drop in the target

Comment: or i didn't understand what you mean